# Dynamic programming: why update array in the reversed order

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I am trying to work through this question in LeetCode.
119. Pascal's Triangle II

Given a non-negative index k where k ≤ 33, return the kth index row of the Pascal's triangle.

Note that the row index starts from 0.

In Pascal's triangle, each number is the sum of the two numbers directly above it.

Example:
[image]
Input: 3
Output: [1,3,3,1]
Follow up:

Could you optimize your algorithm to use only O(k) extra space?

```
import java.util.Arrays;
class Solution {
    public List<Integer> getRow(int rowIndex) {
    Integer[] dp = new Integer[rowIndex+1];
    Arrays.fill(dp,1);
    for(int i = 2; i <= rowIndex;i++){
        for(int j = i- 1; j > 0;j--){
            dp[j] = dp[j-1] + dp[j];
        }
    }
    return Arrays.asList(dp);
    }
}
```

And I see some one giving this working solution.
I can understand why it is correct.
But I am still quite unclear why the array is updating in this order.
In this case I know the transition of status is like:

**P(n) = P(n-1) + P(n)**

But how can this give clues on how to choose the direction of updating the array?
Why exactly the ascending order doesn't work in this case if we think in the way of DP. I know substantially this could cause duplicated calculation.

I know this may be subtle but still how anyone could at least cast even a little light on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly the formula *P<sub>n</sub> = P<sub>n-1</sub> + P<sub>n</sub>* brings confusion, as it is not a true recurrence relationship. If it were, it would be infinite.

The true recurrence relationship is given by:

*P<sub>row, n</sub> = P<sub>row-1, n-1</sub> + P<sub>row-1, n</sub>*

Or in more complete terms:

- *∀ n ∈ {1, row-1}: P<sub>row, n</sub> = P<sub>row-1, n-1</sub> + P<sub>row-1, n</sub>*
- *P<sub>row, 0</sub> = 1*
- *P<sub>n, n</sub> = 1*

If you would implement this naively, you would create a 2-dimensional DP matrix. Starting with row 0, you would build up the DP matrix going from one row to the next, using the above recurrence relationship.

You then find that you only need the previous row's DP data to calculate the current row's. All the DP rows that come before the previous one are idle: they don't serve any purpose anymore. They are a waste of space.

So then you decide to not create a whole DP matrix, but just two rows. Once you have completed the second row of this DP structure, you make that row the first, and reset the second row in the DP structure. And then you can continue filling that second row, until it is complete again, and you repeat this "shift" of rows...

And now we come to the last optimisation, which brings us to your question:

You can actually do it with one DP row. That row will represent both the previous DP row as the current. For that to work, you need to update that row from right to left.

Every value that is updated is considered "current row", and every value that you read is considered "previous row". That way the right side of the recurrence relation refers to the previous DP row, and the left side (that is assigned) to the current.

This works only from right to left, because the recurrence formula never refers to *n+1*, but to *n* at the most. If it would have referred to *n* and *n+1*, then you would have had to go from left to right.

At the moment we *read* the value at *n*, it is still the value that corresponds to the previous DP row, and once we write to it, we will not need that previous value anymore. And when we *read* the value at *n-1* we are sure it is still the previous row's value, since we come from the right, and did not update it yet.

You can imagine how we wipe-and-replace the values of the "previous" row with the new values of the "current" row.

Hope this clarifies it a bit.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification. I finally started to see that there are quite a series of optimization that is what I think probably hinder my understanding. I just implemented a [2][rowIndex+1] 2-dimention array which shows me the way to the final optimization.